# Pandas: expand dataframe row-wise, similar to R's SurvSplit()

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of people and years employed:

```
person_id  years                
1          1.00
2          2.34
3          6.85
```

I want to expand the dataframe row-wise based upon pre-defined "chunks" in the employee's tenure.  For example, if I want to chunk people's tenure at the 1 yr mark, the above dataframe would become:

```
person_id  tstart  tend                 
1          0.00    1.00
2          0.00    1.00
2          1.00    2.34
3          0.00    1.00
3          1.00    6.85
```

If I wanted to chunk at the 1 yr AND 2 yr mark, the original dataframe becomes:

```
person_id  tstart  tend                 
1          0.00    1.00
2          0.00    1.00
2          1.00    2.00
2          2.00    2.34
3          0.00    1.00
3          1.00    2.00
3          2.00    6.85
```

So, ideally, I want to provide a `list` or `tuple` of chunks to direct the row-wise expansion (e.g. `[1,2]` to chunk at years 1 and 2)

This dataframe manipulation would be similar to R's `survSplit()` - see pg 127 [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/survival.pdf)

How can I do this?  I found a few articles on Stackoverflow but they discuss different dataframe expansion goals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following defined method. Though a bit of a walk-through it uses no loops unlike [survsplit](https://github.com/cran/survival/blob/master/src/survsplit.c) actual source code which is written in C.

Below essentially runs a cross join of iterative tenure years to max of *chunk* arg and merges to the point of persons' *years*. Then, original dataframe values with calculated *tstart* and *tend* columns is concatenated on the `merge` result. A *key* must be assigned to original dataframe, here being *persons*:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

persons = pd.read_table(StringIO("""person_id  years                
1          1.00
2          2.34
3          6.85"""), sep="\s+").assign(key = 1)

def expand_tenure(chunk):
    newpersons = persons.assign(tstart = chunk, tend = persons['years'])
    newpersons.loc[newpersons['tend'] < chunk, 'tstart'] = np.floor(persons['years'])

    df = pd.DataFrame({'tstart': list(range(0, chunk)),
                       'tend': list(range(1, chunk+1)),
                       'key': 1})

    mdf = pd.merge(persons, df, on='key')    
    mdf = mdf[mdf['tend'] <= mdf['years']][['person_id', 'tstart', 'tend']]

    cdf = pd.concat([newpersons[['person_id', 'tstart', 'tend']], mdf])\
                    .sort_values(['person_id', 'tstart'])\
                    .drop_duplicates(['person_id', 'tend']).reset_index(drop=True)

    return cdf
```

**Output** *(three runs)*

```
print(expand_tenure(1))
#    person_id  tstart  tend
# 0          1     0.0  1.00
# 1          2     0.0  1.00
# 2          2     1.0  2.34
# 3          3     0.0  1.00
# 4          3     1.0  6.85

print(expand_tenure(4))
#    person_id  tstart  tend
# 0          1     0.0  1.00
# 1          2     0.0  1.00
# 2          2     1.0  2.00
# 3          2     2.0  2.34
# 4          3     0.0  1.00
# 5          3     1.0  2.00
# 6          3     2.0  3.00
# 7          3     3.0  4.00
# 8          3     4.0  6.85

print(expand_tenure(12))
#     person_id  tstart  tend
# 0           1     0.0  1.00
# 1           2     0.0  1.00
# 2           2     1.0  2.00
# 3           2     2.0  2.34
# 4           3     0.0  1.00
# 5           3     1.0  2.00
# 6           3     2.0  3.00
# 7           3     3.0  4.00
# 8           3     4.0  5.00
# 9           3     5.0  6.00
# 10          3     6.0  6.85
```